# dynamic collectionView in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a dynamic collectionView in TableView and there are three errors:

1. the cells are not displayed correctly when the application starts
2. when I do `inserItem` the cells flicker as if they are rebooting
3. **and most importantly**  when `collectionView.insertItems` the first four cells are hidden, the [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DRXLXQgXhrc__ImDjZMDoqrEJdCKFIKs/view?usp=sharing)

   **thanks**

MainViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {


  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setting()
    }

  func setting(){

   getData()

   tableView.dataSource = self
   tableView.delegate = self

   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension 
   tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension    

  }

         //load data
   func pagination(_ completion: (()->())?){

      SmartNetworkSevrice.getGoods(with: url) { [unowned self] (data) in
         guard data.modals.count > 0 else {
             self.tableView.tableFooterView = nil
             return
         }

         self.goods.append(contentsOf: data.modals)
         self.offSet += data.modals.count
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
             self.tableView.tableFooterView = nil
             if self.goods.count == data.modals.count || self.isRefresh {
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
             } else {
                if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TVCellGoods {
                    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                        cell.insertGoods(data.modals)
                        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                        cell.collectionViewHeight.constant = cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
                        self.tableView.endUpdates()
                     }

                }
             }
            completion?()
         }
     }

     // define bottom of tableView
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        guard scrollView == self.tableView else {  return }
        if (!isMoreDataLoading) {

            // Вычислить позицию длины экрана до нижней части результатов
            let scrollViewContentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
            let scrollOffsetThreshold = scrollViewContentHeight - scrollView.bounds.size.height
            if(scrollView.contentOffset.y > scrollOffsetThreshold && scrollView.isDragging) {
                isMoreDataLoading = true
                self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = false;
                self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true;
                pagination(nil)
            }
        }

       }

    }

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "goods", for: indexPath) as? TVCellGoods else { return UITableViewCell() }
              guard bestGoods.count != 0, goods.count != 0 else { return UITableViewCell() }
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.configure(bestGoods, goods, categories)
            // автообновление высоты
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            cell.collectionViewHeight.constant = cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
            return cell 
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, CallDelegate {

    func callMethod() {}

    func callMethod(push vc:UIViewController) {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

}
```

TableViewCell with collectionView

```
class TVCellGoods: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView:UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeight:NSLayoutConstraint!

    weak var delegate:CallDelegate?
    var bestGoods = [Goods]() // лучшие товары
    var goods = [Goods]() // все товары
    var categories = [Menu]()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.tag = 2
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func configure(_ best:[Goods],_ goods:[Goods], _ category:[Menu]) {

        self.bestGoods = best
        self.goods = goods
        self.categories = category
        self.collectionView.reloadData()

    }

    func insertGoods(_ data:[Goods]) {

        self.goods.append(contentsOf: data)
        let count = self.bestGoods.count + self.categories.count  + self.goods.count
        let indexPaths = ((count - data.count) ..< count)
            .map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
        self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            self.collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths)
        }, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

and CollectionViewCell

```
class CVCellGoods: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var bgView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var delivery: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var premium: UIImageView!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        delivery.image = nil
        premium.image = nil
        title.text = nil
        price.text = nil
        imageView.image = nil
        imageView.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 215/255, green: 215/255, blue: 215/255, alpha: 1)

        self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0.5)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

    }

}
```

**EDIT:** this gives a small bug at startup

TVCellGoods.swift

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I just figured out how to solve your problem.
You gonna have to invalidate your collection view layout, as you are using an collectionView inside a tableView just add the following method on TVCellGoods.swift

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

I tested it, and worked!! 
see [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14Jo7AkdnknIO0qWvj_8nq6cQiJ-ueFc_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: this gives a small bug at startup. photo at the end of the question

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to add a scroll view inside another scroll view!
Do you have an example project in order to help you?

Comment: initially I had a scrollView with collectionView, I increased the height depending on the number of products but when pagination was slow.

Comment: I did a test project https://drive.google.com/file/d/1klq1Y6caxQBR5l2ySajE-XDb6mRKGgW-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, Just give me 1 o 2 days, I'm working on a solution for you but right now I'm a bit busy with my projects.

Comment: were able to decide?

Answer (score 0):

> the cells are not displayed correctly when the application starts

You calculate collectionView itemSize in ViewDidLoad,

but in ViewDidLoad TableView & TableviewCell width not equal ViewController.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(view.frame.size.width) //320
    print(tableView.frame.size.width) //414
}
```

You can try reloadData in ViewDidAppear.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    print(view.frame.size.width) //320
    print(tableView.frame.size.width) //320
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

> when collectionView.insertItems the first four cells are hidden

Subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout

```
class MyCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout  {
      override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
         return true
    }
}
```

TVCellGoods.swift

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.tag = 2
    collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = MyCollectionViewFlowLayout()
}
```